# How to validate a input filed to moble number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I wrote the below code for validating an input of form for accept mobile numbers with condition of maximum number 11 and start with 0 otherwise show the error: please enter a valid mobile number

I wrote a function but it is not working correctly. If I put a number more than 11 the form will true. Even if I wrote a number without 0 it will accept.
here is my codes:

```js
$('#mobili').focusout(function() {
    $('#mobili').filter(function() {
        var mobi = $('#mobili').val();
        var mobiback = $('#mobili');
        var mobilReg = /(\+989|9|09)(12|19|35|36|37|38|39|32)\d{7}/;
        if (!mobilReg.test(mobi)) {
            $('#mobili').css('background-color', '#ff6666');
            $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#ff6666');
            $("#error-nwl").text("please enter a valid mobile number");
        } else {
            $('#mobili').css('background-color', '#66cc66');
            $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#66cc66');
            $("#error-nwl").text("ok");
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <input type="tel" name="field1" id="mobili" />
        <input type="submit" />
        <div id="error-nwl"></div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I believe that if you add the start of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors it would work as you want.  `/^(\+989|9|09)(12|19|35|36|37|38|39|32)\d{7}$/`

Comment: You say that the number should be 11 digits and begin with 0, but your regex is will capture a group of 10 digits starting with a 0, 11 digits starting with 09, or 12 digits starting with +989. Gaby's comment is correct about adding the anchors, but what kind of number are you actually trying to capture?

Comment: @denmch i want to type a mobile number start with 0

Comment: Your regex breaks down as follows: First capture group: "989" or "9" or "09".
Second capture group: "12 or 19 or 35 or 36 or 37 or 38 or 39 or 32". Then 7 digits.

Comment: To just capture 11 digits beginning with a 0, you could use ^0\d{10}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i got from your problem is you need regular expression to validate field which should accept 11 digit number starting from 0 so use regular expression

```
/^([0][0-9]{10})$/
```

and you can fix max length in input as well using

```
maxlength="11"
```

```js
$('#mobili').focusout(function() {
    $('#mobili').filter(function() {
        var mobi = $('#mobili').val();
        var mobiback = $('#mobili');
        var mobilReg = /^([0][0-9]{10})$/;
        if (!mobilReg.test(mobi)) {
            $('#mobili').css('background-color', '#ff6666');
            $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#ff6666');
            $("#error-nwl").text("please enter a valid mobile number");
        } else {
            $('#mobili').css('background-color', '#66cc66');
            $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#66cc66');
            $("#error-nwl").text("ok");
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <input type="tel" name="field1" id="mobili" maxlength="11" />
        <input type="submit" />
        <div id="error-nwl"></div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```